# How can I keep a VPN connection alive?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, vpn, bittorrent

I've been trying to find a way to run a torrent client strictly through a VPN. I am running Ubuntu 9.10, and use Ktorrent. I can connect to vpn.itshidden.com but I am worried about the connection dropping if I'm away from my computer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From [VPNC seems to timeout quickly- how do I lengthen the timeout?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/vpnc-seems-to-timeout-quickly-how-do-i-lengthen-the-timeout-478494/)

> To keep the VPNC connection open
>   indefinitely add this line
>  DPD
>   idle timeout (our side) 0
>  to your
>   .conf file in /etc/vpnc and I think
>   that will effectively resolve the
>   timeout problem.
>
> For example:

```
IPSec gateway <your_gateway>
IPSec ID linux
IPSec secret <your_group_password>
Xauth username <your_username>
DPD idle timeout (our side) 0
```

Comment: harrymc, thank you for your post. I just want to make sure I'm dong this right.
When I type in my info, do I need to keep the < > signs?
And does that just stay as (our side) or do I need to put something in there?
Sorry if this sounds stupid, I'm new to this.

Comment: 2 more things: is the IPSec secret my VPN account password?
And what name do I save the .conf file under?

Comment: @Al: The <> have no meaning, and all the data relates to the VPN. See also this article: http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1293/ubuntu%20linux%20VPN%20connection%20without%20cisco%20vpn%20client

Answer (score 0):

Set up a cron job to do a ping to your VPN...
Something like ***/10 * * * * root ping -c 3 any.vpn.ip.address** in your /etc/crontab should do (it will do a ping every 10 minutes)

Comment: I just tried what you told me but it didn't work. I copied exactly what you typed.. Did I need to change anything? I have to apologize, I'm not to familiar with this so you may have to explain. The VPN I'm trying to connect to is vpn.itshidden.com, did I need to put that in the place of any.vpn.Ip.address?

Comment: Yes, put the hostname or IP address of something that requires the VPN.

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: What distro are you running?
What did not work?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 9.10 32 bit. I copied and pasted */10 * * * * root ping -c 3 vpn.itshidden.com into /etc/crontab. I connected to my VPN account and it timed out and wouldn't come back on. I thought I may have had to restart the PC, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested to see if the connection drops when you are away from your computer?If your torrent client is passing data through the connection it should definitely stay alive.